# Disable save prompt for specific workbooks

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I regularly read some Excel workbooks, to which I've only read access.

As I generally change filtering in them I'm asked whether to save before closing them. I never want to save them.

Is there a way to disable save prompt?

I've found solutions with macros (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674867/how-to-disable-the-save-as-prompt), however as I've written I have only read access to those workbooks, so can't add a macro to them.

Comment: Save the macro to your `personal.xlsb` so it is available in any workbook.

Comment: How? According to my understanding code needs to be placed in `Workbook_BeforeSave`.

Comment: Good point. It was just a guess since I have not had time to look into this today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code o\in your personal workbook:

```
Sub CloseNoSave()
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
End Sub
```

Then attach that macro to a button using the Quick Access Toolbar
[image: Quick Access Toolbar Menu]
Select Macro from the drop down menu
[image: Macro Selection]
and add the macro to the toolbar.
Use this button instead of File/Close or the X in the corner, and you should not be prompted

**Warning** - You will not be prompted, and it will close the active workbook, so use with caution, as Auto Recover may not work so save you if you use it on the wrong file